# Unexplained Border on side of iframe

Tags: html, css

I have a page that I'm working on (https://docs.focusfwd.com/) that has an iframe that is displaying a border on the left side. The border is set to 0 and I can't figure out from exploring the html/css what is causing it.  If you look at the source URL of the iframe, the border doesn't appear there, so it isn't coming from that source. Any ideas on what might be causing that to render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your table rows has a `<th>` at the start that's getting squashed down to a single pixel. Force a width on them, and you'll see they're the culprit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It seems like this may be an issue with how those row labels are being hidden by Google Sheets when you use the flag to hide those in their publish settings, so not something I was doing wrong in my css.